# Android org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject class not found

Tags: java, android

I am using ksoap2-android-assembly-2.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar file and I am getting Could not find class 'org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject', referenced from method com.falafel.myTest.FirstScreen.onCreate this error and on Emulator showing "Unfortunately file is stopped". Kindly help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

I think this is eclipse version problem.

So try to add the library file into `libs` folder,

that is create folder with name "libs" and 
put the library for which library you have used..

I hope this will be help to you..